# Why 403 forbidden error for pip install with proxy configured in pip.ini file?

Tags: pip

My python version is "Python 3.6.3" and pip version is "pip 9.0.1" on windows OS. I am running this in a proxy network and have already setup pip.ini inside pip folder inside python installation directory.

below is the content of my file

```
[global]
proxy = http://username:password@1@proxy:port

trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org
```

I am getting 403 forbidden error for all pip install commands, even for "pip install --upgrade pip" I am getting the same. Please suggest any solution.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: `http://username:password@1@proxy:port` — strange syntax. Why two `@`s?

Comment: [global]
proxy = http://username:password@proxy:port

trusted-host = pypi.python.org
               pypi.org
               files.pythonhosted.org

Comment: that was typo, only one @ is there and I have not given my proxy, username, port and password in this powt, it's just the format which I have mentioned.